# Display RAW XML to a string or Label and find out particular Tag from that XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-2.0

[image]

I will get this in a Raw format and i am writing this using

```
      Response.write("Some.xml");
```

I need to find out MerchantOrderNumber from this raw data how to obtain this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet would be to load the XML into an XML parser e.g. [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse.aspx):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse("SomeXml");
string merchantOrderNumber = xdoc.Descendants("MerchantOrderNumber").First().Value;
```

**Edit**

If you are using .NET 2.0 then you can use [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kza7w4k%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) e.g.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXML("SomeXml");
string merchantOrderNumber = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("MerchantOrderNumber")[0].InnerText;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using XPath, something like this:

```
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument("Some.xml");
XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
XPathExpression expr = nav.Compile("/xml/Order/MerchantOrderNumber");
XPathNodeIterator nodes = nav.Select(expr);
string merchNum = string.Empty;
if(nodes.MoveNext())
{
   merchNum = nodes.Current.Value;
}
```